# Pandas python 2.7 precision decimal

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am doing data validation and need python to register a long float integer as a regular float and not in the 1.2e+12 format. Can anyone point me in the right direction? i am using pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{0:.2f}'.format
```

This will represent the value with precision of 2 decimals and will include the whole representation.

Comment: Doesnt seem to be working. Does the above function change the value to a string?